# How to discover Heroku bottleneck on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running a Rails 2.3.11 app on Heroku Bamboo stack and I'm getting awful performance issues, as lots of pages take more than 15-30 seconds to load (resulting in frequent timeout errors).

The same app running on my local development environment, using the same database load, instead runs reasonably well (around 1000 milliseconds).

I've tried to use addons as NewRelic but I cannot make sense of it, I find it too difficult to understand.
Basically I need to understand if my bottleneck are slow db queries, slow remote urls (es: google maps api queries), some misconfiguration issue or the infamous Heroku random routing.

What would you suggest me to do?

**UPDATE**

As suggested I had a look at the logs and for instance when I call the homepage I get this result:

Completed in 8014ms (View: 437, DB: 698) | 200 OK

What does it mean that it is completed in 8014ms when the sum of the milliseconds of the DB and the View should be around 1 second?

Comment: Watch the log file as you make some requests and analyze it.  It should give you a better idea of what is slow.

Comment: While you're at it, upgrade Rails. 2.3.11 is wildly outdated and filled with security holes.

Comment: and Heroku will encourage you to move to Cedar - away from Bamboo.

Comment: I can consider moving away from Bamboo but first I would need to understand if this could be the cause of my performance issues.

Comment: Philip, I had look at the logs as you suggested and I updated the question.

Comment: I'd go back to trying to understand NewRelic - it's meant to help diagnose these issues and there's not enough info in your question to accurately suggest a fix. The problem could be any/all of the things you suggest.